# Oozie on YARN - oozie is not allowed to impersonate hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie, ambari

I'm trying to use Oozie from Java to start a job on a Hadoop cluster. I have very limited experience with Oozie on Hadoop 1 and now I'm struggling trying out the same thing on YARN.

I'm given a machine that doesn't belong to the cluster, so when I try to start my job I get the following exception:

```
E0501 : E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, User: oozie is not allowed to impersonate hadoop
```

Why is that and what to do?

I read a bit about core-site properties that need to be set

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
  <value>users</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
  <value>master</value>
</property>
```

Does it seem that this is the problem? Should I contact people responsible for cluster to fix that?

Could there be problems because I'm using same code for YARN as I did for Hadoop 1? Should something be changed? For example, I'm setting nameNode and jobTracker in workflow.xml, should jobTracker exist, since there is now ResourceManager? I have set the address of ResourceManager, but left the property name as jobTracker, could that be the error?

Maybe I should also mention that Ambari is used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please update the core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
```

and jobTracker address is the Resourcemananger address that will not be the case . once update the core-site.xml file it will works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but won't that enable any user to submit workflows using Oozie? I'm only one of the Oozie users, I don't think that cluster administrators will allow this setup... Is there a way impersonate as a different user while running the workflow from java code?

Comment: you are trying to submit the job in "hadoop" user! then you can add the user "hadoop" to the user "oozie". here "hadoop" is the OOZIE_SERVER_HOSTNAME so that we have to add to the user.

Comment: So you are saying that in the configuration should be <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>? 

Is it possible to perform -doAs from java code? What property to specify?

Comment: yes, because the hadoop is the user who submitting the oozie jobs. another solution is that set the JAVA_PROPERTY as -Duser.name=hadoop in the %oozie_home%/bin/oozie.sh(bat). for -doAS we can add the hadoop user to the group oozie.

Answer (score 0):

Reason:
Cause of this type of error is- You run oozie server as a hadoop user but you  define oozie as a proxy user in core-site.xml file.

Solution:

change the ownership of oozie installation directory to oozie user and run oozie server as a oozie user and problem will be solved.